# How to submit a form on page load without using jquery in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, http-post

I have a form in AngularJS application. I need to auto submit this form upon page load without using jquery because of cross domain issue.

When I submit the form by using a submit button it works and the target url loads in the browser. If I remove the submit button and try to submit in the onload event, 
it does not work. The page displays just ";". Any idea why onload does not work here? Thank you!

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="@Model.Settings["URL"]" ng-controller="PostCtrl">
    <input type="hidden" name="Name" value="{{Details.Name}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="Amount" value="{{Details.Amount}}">

     @*<button type="submit" class="action blue"><span class="label">Click here</span></button>*@

    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            document.myForm.submit();
        }
    </script>
</form>
```

Comment: you can submit the form in your angular controller instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some suggestions for you. But first you have to add an id to your form: 1: Go to your `<html>` element and call the onload function there --> `<html onload="document.getElementById('yourform').submit();">` or 2: call the JavaScript function with php

```
<?php
echo "<script>document.getElementById('yourform').submit();</script>";
?>
```

Or 3: try to change your Script to

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById('yourform').submit();
        }
</script>
```